# Sending a message to a specific routee in a pool

Tags: scala, akka

Say I have a pool of Routee actors and each of these actors has its own 'subordinate' actor it needs to communicate with. When a the subordinate sends a message back to the 'parent' routee it seems that this message is also being passed through router so there is no guarantee that it will make it to the appropriate router. So take the code below:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

    val router = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props(new Routee)), "myrouter")

    def receive = {

        case msg: SomeMsg => router ! msg
    } 

}

class Routee extends Actor {

    val sub = context.actorOf(Props(new Subordinate(this)))
    var waiting = false

    def receive = {

        case msg: SomeMsg => 
            if (! waiting) {
                waiting = true
                sub ! msg
            }

        case ack: SomeAck =>
            waiting = false
            if (ack.routee != this) println("From a different subordinate")
    }
}

class Subordinate(routee: Routee) extends Actor {

    def receive = {

        case msg: SomeMsg =>
            sender ! SomeAck(routee)
    }

}
```

So if I run the code below this will cause the "From a different subordinate" message to printed:

```
    val actor = ActorSystem("test").actorOf(Props(new MyActor), "myactor")
    while (true) actor ! SomeMsg()
```

There is no guarantee that I the acknowledgement is sent back to the appropriate routee. Is it the case that the acknowledgement is being passed through the router and if so is there a way around this?

Configuration:

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"

        deployment {
            /myactor/myrouter {
                router = balancing-pool
                nr-of-instances = 4
            }
        }
    }
    remote {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
        netty.tcp {
            hostname = "0.0.0.0"
            port = 2551
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an actual problem here or not?  Your `Subordinate` responds to the `sender()`, which will be whoever sent the `SomeMsg` to it.  In this case it's the instance of `Routee` from the pool, so the one that sent it should get the `Ack` back directly w/o going back through the pool.

Comment: But if that were the case why would "From a different subordinate" get printed?

Comment: You need to show your configuration or else it will be impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Also a **warning**: you are passing around internal actor state when you are giving away this, an actor should never let anybody else see their internal state, so if you want to do something like this you have two safe options which are passing `self` to `Subordinate` or using `context.parent` inside of `Subordinate`

Comment: You are referring to the routee reference passed in the constructor I take it. I only added this to prove the point and it would not be part of a solution of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `balancing-pool`, which means that the routees will use a shared mailbox and "steal" each other's messages. Try with `round-robin-pool` instead.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid this when using some kind of balancing pool I guess